# From C/C++ to NASM src

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, nasm

I need to develope some algorithms that are really easy to do with a hig level language as C or C++, but become really hard to write directly as NASM istructions.

Since basically a C and C++ compiler have to use low level istructions to produce binaries, is there a simple way to obtain the NASM code from C\C++ programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man gcc`:

> **-S**
>
> Stop after the stage of compilation proper; do not assemble. The output is in the form of an assembler code file for each non-assembler
>   input file specified.
>
> By default, the assembler file name for a source file is made by
>   replacing the suffix .c, .i, etc., with .s.

`gcc -S hello.c` should create file `hello.s` with corresponding assembler code.

Works for `g++` too.
Other compilers probably have similar option.

---

For example, for this program (`hello.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world! %d\n", 6*7);
    return 0;
}
```

The output (`hello.s`) contains this:

```
        .file   "hello.c"
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "Hello, world! %d\n"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movl    $42, %esi
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
        movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: I have tried but the generated code is really confused and difficoult to understand also with small method. the same method written directly in NASM is definitely smaller. any suggestion?

Comment: @AndreaF Yes, there is lot of noise. But it is the exact output that goes from compiler to assembler. Lot of it is just for proper function calling, parameter handling, stack maintenance... If you write it by hand yourself, you can do these things simpler. But the core functionality is present and is visible after a little search (I suggest to look after function names in labels).

Comment: @AndreasF: That's just the way generated assembly output is. It has to be compatible with the rest of C and it tries to make things efficient. There's no reason for it to make it readable so it doesn't try to. In fact, that would probably make the program run poorly in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to compile (with -g to see the source code along with the assembly) and run objdump on the binary

```
objdump -M intel -d a.out
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. could you give me more details about the use of this command line? What are the parameters `intel` and `a.out` and `-M`?

Comment: -M intel tells objdump to display the assembly in Intel syntax, which is arguably better than the (AT&T)default syntax.. a.out is just the name of the file you want to disassemble.